VBA formula dentro del codigo
quiero suplantar el nombre completo del libro ([5-Previsión.xlsx]) por el nombre asignado en VBA en esta formula que esta dentro del codigo VBA
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6]&RC[-2],'[5-Previsión.xlsx]PREVISION VACACIONES SG'!R1:R1048576,12,0),""No Encontrado"")"

Suponiendo no conoces el nombre del libro que hay (5-Previsión.xlsx), para hacerlo mas general.
Hay que buscar la primera y la ultima letra de ese nombre.
El nuevo texto será los dos trozos, anterior y posterior, intercalando el nuevo nombre de libro.
Dim a, b As String
Dim n, m As Long
a = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6]&RC[-2],'[5-Previsión.xlsx]PREVISION VACACIONES SG'!R1:R1048576,12,0),""No Encontrado"")"
n = InStr(a, "'") + 2 ' Primera letra del libro
b = Mid(a, n)
m = n + InStr(b, "]") - 2 ' Ultima letra del libro
b = Mid(a, 1, n - 1) & "NUEVO.xlsx" & Mid(a, m + 1)

